# Combining two YV12 image buffers into a single side-by-side image

Tags: c++, yuv, color-space

I have two image buffers in YV12 format that I need to combine into a single side-by-side image.

(1920x1080) + (1920x1080) = (3840*1080)

YV12 is split into 3 seperate planes.

```
YYYYYYYY VV UU
```

The pixel format is 12 bits-per-pixel.

I have created a method that `memcpy`s one buffer (1920x1080) into a larger buffer (3840x1080), but it isn't working.

Here is my c++.

```
BYTE* source = buffer;
BYTE* destination = convertBuffer3D;

// copy over the Y
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, width);
    destination += width * 2;
    source += width;
}

// copy over the V
for (int x = 0; x < (height / 2); x++)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, width / 2);
    destination += width;
    source += width / 2;
}

// copy over the U
for (int x = 0; x < (height / 2); x++)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, width / 2);
    destination += width;
    source += width / 2;
}
```

I expected this:

[image: Correct image]

Instead, I get this result:

[image: Incorrect image]

What am I missing?

Comment: The code looks about right. You are perhaps missing something else (stride on either of the images is extended? bottom padding?).

Comment: No extended stride our padding. The total buffer size of my 1920x1080 image is 3110400 (1920x1080x1.5), so no additional data.

Comment: Also I suppose a similar effect would be if it was NV12 rather than YV12. Then you need to simply check source and destination after the loops. If they are correct, then the problem is not with the loops, but rather with image structure which is different from what you expect it to be.

Comment: @RomanR, correct. NV12 is the same as YV12, except the U/V data is interleaved, instead of in different planes.

Comment: Not only interleaved, with NV12 Y is the same (as in your case) and UVs are copied in different blocks (can result in what is on your images).

Answer (score 3):

What you wanted is this:

```
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
U1 U1 U2 U2 V1 V1 V2 V2
U1 U1 U2 U2 V1 V1 V2 V2
```

but your code is actually doing this:

```
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
Y1 Y1 Y1 Y1 Y2 Y2 Y2 Y2
U1 U1 V1 V1 U2 U2 V2 V2
U1 U1 V1 V1 U2 U2 V2 V2
```

Here's the corrected code (untested)

```
BYTE* source = buffer;
BYTE* destination = convertBuffer3D;

// copy over the Y
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, width);
    destination += width * 2;
    source += width;
}

for (int x = 0; x < (height / 2); x++)
{
    // copy over the V
    memcpy(destination, source, width / 2);
    destination += width;
    source += width / 2;

    // copy over the U
    memcpy(destination, source, width / 2);
    destination += width;
    source += width / 2;
}
```