# Combining two YV12 image buffers into a single side-by-side image Java/Android

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin

This question has answer in C++.
Is there any way to do the same or to invoke the code from Java/Android side?

[Combining two YV12 image buffers into a single side-by-side image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404312/combining-two-yv12-image-buffers-into-a-single-side-by-side-image)

What is this code analogues in java/kotlin?

```
BYTE* source = buffer;
BYTE* destination = convertBuffer3D;
```

This memcpy function ( taken from c++ reference [memcopy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) ) has any analogues?

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a native func via JNI?

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that cannot be expressed in Java just as easily. What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/
This memcpy function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you dont use the one of the Java array copy, the `System.arraycopy` or the class method `java.util.Arrays.copyOf`.

```
 byte[] source_arr = {0,1,2};
 byte[] dest_arr = Arrays.copyOf(source_arr , source_arr.length);
```

**arraycopy**

u can use the arraycopy. see oracle docs [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
                             int srcPos,
                             Object dest,
                             int destPos,
                             int length)
```

since java have no `unsigned char` or `c++ byte` data type like. the only way i know to achieve similar data type (`BYTE`) c++ like is by downcasting integer type to byte:

```
int var = 128;
byte _BYTE = (byte)128;
```